# When creating a derived class in C#, is it possible to overwrite a 0 parameter virtual function with an n parameter function?

Tags: c#, function, inheritance, overriding, virtual

I checked out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx) and a couple other sites but I'm still not sure I got an answer for this. If you have a Parent class with a virtual function Init(), can I then--in the derived class--have an override function Init(int num) or do you simply have to create a new function for each derived class you make? If I'm not mistake, the latter would cause you to have 2 Init functions in the Child class, right? Here's sort of what I mean:

```
    public class Parent {
        protected int a;

        public Parent() {
            a=1;
        }

        public virtual void Init() {
        }
    }

    public class Child : Parent {

        public Child() {
        }

        //is this allowed?
        public override void Init(int multiplier) {
        }

        //or do i have to do this and have 2 Init functions?
        public void Init(int multiplier) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You're not actually overriding the method, you're simply defining a new overload.

To be able to override a method, the base method must be declared a `public` (or `protected`) `virtual` (or `abstract`) method and your derived class must use the same exact signature.

In your case, no overridable method with that signature exists in the base class so it is not allowed.  It *would* be allowed if an overridable method existed with the signature `Init(int)` but there isn't, the compiler would yield an error here.

Comment: This is actually what I figured. Guess that means I'll just leave it up to the derived classes to have their own Init functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.
What would the parameter be if it's called from the base class?

Answer (score 0):

An override needs to have the same signature, otherwise there is no point in making it virtual.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //is this allowed?
    public override void Init(int multiplier) {
    }
```

This is not an override.

Since you are introducing new multiplier it would be considered new method.

However if you do this.

```
      public override void Init(){}
```

It will be override.

However if you do this in derived class it will be considered overload.

```
       public void Init(int Multiplier)
       {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will give you an error, because "there is nothing to override".

Basically, the overridden method must match the underlying signature:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx